# clusters in geo mapping

Tags: javascript, dictionary, geolocation, openlayers

In a map, I would like to cluster my results. So far I've only seen cluster tools that further zoom in. What I want is to have a fixed map and, that, if clicked, the cluster will open itself. I tried to visualize what I want to do in the picture below:

[image: Goal]

Now, does anyone have an idea how to do this? Are there solutions for this already?

Thanks in advance,

Maurice

Answer (score 2):

http://code.google.com/p/eaditor/source/browse/trunk/javascript/result_map_functions.js

is a good example

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with OpenLayers (www.openlayers.org) using a Cluster Strategy. That will allow you to display a single point for close points.

Then you need to write code that controls the popups on hover/click. I can;t find an example that does that for the cluster strategy specifically, but there are examples of popups for OpenLayers in the docs. Some javascript skills should get you what you want.

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/ and filter for 'cluster' or 'popup'